# CSV File Content Display Issue

Tags: php, csv

I want to retrieve contents from a csv file for that i am using following code:

```
<?php
     $fo = fopen("record.csv", "rb+");
     while(!feof($fo)) {
          $contents[] = fgetcsv($fo,0,';');
     }
     print_r($contents);
     fclose($fo);

?>
```

But my records are displayed in the following format:

```
䅲牡礊⠊††嬰崠㴾⁁牲慹ਠ††† ਠ†††††⁛そ‽㸠"Search Transactions Results" ††††⤊ਠ†⁛ㅝ‽㸠䅲牡礊††††⠊††††††嬰崠㴾 ∀吀爀愀渀猀愀挀琀椀漀渀 䤀䐀∀Ⰰ∀刀攀昀攀爀攀渀挀攀 吀爀愀渀猀愀挀琀椀漀
```

My csv file format:

```
"Search Transactions Results"
"Transaction ID","Reference Transaction ID","Date","Type","Subject","Item Number","Item Name","Invoice ID","Name","Email","Shipping Name","Shipping Address Line 1","Shipping Address Line 2","Shipping Address City","Shipping State/Province","Shipping Zip/Postal Code","Shipping Address Country","Shipping Method","Address Status","Contact Phone Number","Gross Amount","Receipt ID","Custom Field","Option 1 Name","Option 1 Value","Option 2 Name","Option 2 Value","Note","Auction Site","Auction User ID","Item URL","Auction Closing Date","Insurance Amount","Currency","Fees","Net Amount","Shipping & Handling Amount","Sales Tax Amount","To Email","Time","Time Zone"
"1T","",5/5/2010 2:10:44 PM,"Payment Processed","CFP Self Study Kit","1","CFP Self Study Kit","","User1","user1@gmail.com","","","","","","","","","N","","68.18","R1","","","","","","","","","",,"","USD","-2.62","65.56","0","0","receiver@gmail.com","01:40","Asia/Calcutta"
"2T","",5/19/2010 4:04:08 PM,"Payment Processed","CFP Self Study Kit","1","CFP Self Study Kit","","User2","user2@gmail.com","","","","","","","","","N","","68.18","R2","","","","","","","","","",,"","USD","-2.62","65.56","0","0","receiver@gmail.com","03:34","Asia/Calcutta"
"3T","1RT",5/19/2010 5:28:45 PM,"Currency Conversion Completed","","","",""," ","","","","","","","","","","N","","17492.6","","","","","","","","","","",,"","INR","0","17492.6","0","0","","04:58","Asia/Calcutta"
"4T","2RT",5/19/2010 5:28:45 PM,"Currency Conversion Completed","","","",""," ","","","","","","","","","","N","","-393.36","","","","","","","","","","",,"","USD","0","-393.36","0","0","","04:58","Asia/Calcutta"
"5T","",5/19/2010 5:28:45 PM,"Transfer to Bank Initiated","P1006","","P1006",""," ","","","","","","","","","","N","","-17492.6","","","","","","","","","","",,"","INR","0","-17492.6","0","0","","04:58","Asia/Calcutta"
"6T","",5/20/2010 5:38:02 PM,"Transfer to Bank Completed","P1006","","P1006",""," ","","","","","","","","","","N","","-17492.6","","","","","","","","","","",,"","INR","0","-17492.6","0","0","","05:08","Asia/Calcutta"
"7T","",5/21/2010 12:32:37 PM,"Payment Processed","FP - LVC Plus","","FP - LVC Plus","","User3","user3@gmail.com","User3","NEW DELHI","BEHIND KARNATAKA BANK LD","SOUTH","NEW DELHI","110023","IN","","N","","283.96","","","","","","","","","","",,"","USD","-9.95","274.01","0","0","receiver@gmail.com","00:02","Asia/Calcutta"
"8T","",5/25/2010 4:40:48 PM,"Transfer to Bank Initiated","P1006","","P1006",""," ","","","","","","","","","","N","","-12569.85","","","","","","","","","","",,"","INR","0","-12569.85","0","0","","04:10","Asia/Calcutta"
"9T","3RT",5/25/2010 4:40:48 PM,"Currency Conversion Completed","","","",""," ","","","","","","","","","","N","","-274.01","","","","","","","","","","",,"","USD","0","-274.01","0","0","","04:10","Asia/Calcutta"
"10T","4RT",5/25/2010 4:40:48 PM,"Currency Conversion Completed","","","",""," ","","","","","","","","","","N","","12569.85","","","","","","","","","","",,"","INR","0","12569.85","0","0","","04:10","Asia/Calcutta"
"11T","",5/26/2010 4:57:39 PM,"Transfer to Bank Completed","P1006","","P1006",""," ","","","","","","","","","","N","","-12569.85","","","","","","","","","","",,"","INR","0","-12569.85","0","0","","04:27","Asia/Calcutta"
"Total","-247.05 USD","-15.19","-262.24"
"Total","0.00 INR","0.00","0.00"
```

I want to retrieve the records where "Type"="Payment Processed". I want to retrieve content in a key value format that is for e.g. Transaction ID->1T as i have to store this values in a database but display is not proper.
I am unable to find out the reason for the same please help me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the b in the rb+ for fopen is binary (whats being outputted) - just use r+;

Comment: thanks for replying but now i am getting this when i changed it to r+

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => þÿ�"�S�e�a�r�c�h� �T�r�a�n�s�a�c�t�i�o�n�s� �R�e�s�u�l�t�s�"� ) [1] => Array ( [0] => �"�T�r�a�n�s�a�c�t�i�o�n�

Comment: If you're still getting that, the original csv isn't plain text - it's encoded as a different character set.

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) - *As of PHP 4.3.2, the default mode is set to binary for all platforms that distinguish between binary and text mode. If you are having problems with your scripts after upgrading, try using the 't' flag as a workaround until you have made your script more portable as mentioned before* . Just make sure you use rt+. Let know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

the above issue was related to encoding . I copied the csv file and pasted in notepad and save as .csv and encoding as ansi. Now the content is coming as

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Search Transactions Results ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Transaction ID,"Reference Transaction ID","Date","Type","Subject","Item Number","Item Name","Invoice ID","Name","Email","Shipping Name","Shipping Address Line 1","Shipping Address Line 2","Shipping Address City","Shipping State/Province","Shipping Zip/Postal Code","Shipping Address Country","Shipping Method","Address Status","Contact Phone Number","Gross Amount","Receipt ID","Custom Field","Option 1 Name","Option 1 Value","Option 2 Name","Option 2 Value","Note","Auction Site","Auction User ID","Item URL","Auction Closing Date","Insurance Amount","Currency","Fees","Net Amount","Shipping & Handling Amount","Sales Tax Amount","To Email","Time","Time Zone" ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 1T,"",5/5/2010 2:10:44 PM,"Payment Processed","CFP Self Study Kit","1","CFP Self Study Kit","","User1","user1@gmail.com","","","","","","","","","N","","68.18","R1","","","","","","","","","",,"","USD","-2.62","65.56","0","0","receiver@gmail.com","01:40","Asia/Calcutta" ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 2T,"",5/19/2010 4:04:08 PM,"Payment Processed","CFP Self Study Kit","1","CFP Self Study Kit","","User2","user2@gmail.com","","","","","","","","","N","","68.18","R2","","","","","","","","","",,"","USD","-2.62","65.56","0","0","receiver@gmail.com","03:34","Asia/Calcutta" ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 3T,"1RT",5/19/2010 5:28:45 PM,"Currency Conversion Completed","","","",""," ","","","","","","","","","","N","","17492.6","","","","","","","","","","",,"","INR","0","17492.6","0","0","","04:58","Asia/Calcutta" ) [5] => Array ( [0] => 4T,"2RT",5/19/2010 5:28:45 PM,"Currency Conversion Completed","","","",""," ","","","","","","","","","","N","","-393.36","","","","","","","","","","",,"","USD","0","-393.36","0","0","","04:58","Asia/Calcutta" ) [6] => Array ( [0] => 5T,"",5/19/2010 5:28:45 PM,"Transfer to Bank Initiated","P1006","","P1006",""," ","","","","","","","","","","N","","-17492.6","","","","","","","","","","",,"","INR","0","-17492.6","0","0","","04:58","Asia/Calcutta" ) [7] => Array ( [0] => 6T,"",5/20/2010 5:38:02 PM,"Transfer to Bank Completed","P1006","","P1006",""," ","","","","","","","","","","N","","-17492.6","","","","","","","","","","",,"","INR","0","-17492.6","0","0","","05:08","Asia/Calcutta" ) [8] => Array ( [0] => 7T,"",5/21/2010 12:32:37 PM,"Payment Processed","FP - LVC Plus","","FP - LVC Plus","","User3","user3@gmail.com","User3","NEW DELHI","BEHIND KARNATAKA BANK LD","SOUTH","NEW DELHI","110023","IN","","N","","283.96","","","","","","","","","","",,"","USD","-9.95","274.01","0","0","receiver@gmail.com","00:02","Asia/Calcutta" ) [9] => Array ( [0] => 8T,"",5/25/2010 4:40:48 PM,"Transfer to Bank Initiated","P1006","","P1006",""," ","","","","","","","","","","N","","-12569.85","","","","","","","","","","",,"","INR","0","-12569.85","0","0","","04:10","Asia/Calcutta" ) [10] => Array ( [0] => 9T,"3RT",5/25/2010 4:40:48 PM,"Currency Conversion Completed","","","",""," ","","","","","","","","","","N","","-274.01","","","","","","","","","","",,"","USD","0","-274.01","0","0","","04:10","Asia/Calcutta" ) [11] => Array ( [0] => 10T,"4RT",5/25/2010 4:40:48 PM,"Currency Conversion Completed","","","",""," ","","","","","","","","","","N","","12569.85","","","","","","","","","","",,"","INR","0","12569.85","0","0","","04:10","Asia/Calcutta" ) [12] => Array ( [0] => 11T,"",5/26/2010 4:57:39 PM,"Transfer to Bank Completed","P1006","","P1006",""," ","","","","","","","","","","N","","-12569.85","","","","","","","","","","",,"","INR","0","-12569.85","0","0","","04:27","Asia/Calcutta" ) [13] => Array ( [0] => Total,"-247.05 USD","-15.19","-262.24" ) [14] => Array ( [0] => Total,"0.00 INR","0.00","0.00" ) [15] => )
```

But i wanted as header->value thing and that for only Type=Payment Processed

For e.g. "Transaction ID"->'1T'